# What does marked as duplicate by Community♦ mean?

Tags: support, closed-questions, duplicates

I came across [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/735838/redis-is-changing-my-authorized-key) which said

> **marked** as duplicate by [Community♦](https://serverfault.com/users/-1/community) 1 hour ago

Usually when a question is closed there will be an indication of who closed it - either five users or one moderator. This one appears to have been closed without going through [review](https://serverfault.com/review/close/history), and the question has no votes.

Under what circumstances will the Community user close questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, there is a way that a user can agree that a question is indeed a duplicate before the five votes or the mod hammer are in.

In that case, [Community♦](https://serverfault.com/users/-1/community) will be blamed for the closure.

[Can we clarify to the OP that their question is not yet closed and the duplicates are only suggestions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930)